# Qual é o oposto do "display none"?

Tags: javascript, css, css3

Antes fiz algumas pesquisas sobre as propriedades do "display".

Pretendo ocultar algumas **div** e usei **display:none**. Pra voltar a exibir as **div** que propriedade do **display** deveria usar ?

(Estou trabalhar com Javascript)

Answer (score 7):

Na realidade o display por default (caso não declares nada em contrário) depende do elemento, no caso de ser [div o `display` default é `block`](https://www.impressivewebs.com/default-css-display-values-html-elements/), já por exemplo em uma imagem ou span (`<img>`, `<span>`) o display default é `inline`

Comment: Fora esses, também temos o `inline-block` e `flex` :)

Comment: @MuriloGambôa , é verdade e até há mais (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display), mas acho (mesmo quase a certeza) que não existem elementos que por default tenham esse `display`

Comment: realmente, nenhum elemento tem por padrão esses displays

Answer (score 4):

O oposto do `display:none` sera `display:block`

Visto que esta a utilizar **Javascript**, considere tambem **jQuery**, podera atingir o mesmo resultado de uma maneira mais facil e intuitiva como por exemplo:

```
jQuery(elemento).hide(); /*para esconder [utiliza display:none]*/

jQuery(elemento).show(); /*para mostrar [utiliza display:block]*/
```

Caso nao seja permitido o **jQuery**, considere utilizar **CSS** juntamente com **Javascript** da seguinte forma:

No ficheiro **CSS**

```
.hide{
   display:none;
}
.show{
   display:block;
}
```

No **Javascript**

```
var elemento = document.getElementById(ID_DO_ELEMENTO);
//esconder
elemento.className="hide";
//mostrar
elemento.className=elemento.className.replace('hide', 'show');
//ou simplesmente removento do 'hide'
elemento.className=elemento.className.replace('hide', '');
```

Comment: Depende, o elemento `span` ou um `li` tem como padrão o `display: inline` e não um `display: block`, isso também pode ser alterado no CSS, [veja aqui sobre isso](http://blog.jquery.com/2015/07/13/jquery-3-0-and-jquery-compat-3-0-alpha-versions-released/).

Comment: Bem visto @Inkeliz. Contudo o autor da pergunta especifica que o elemento em questao e **div**. Logo excusado estar a explicar tudo sobre **CSS**

Answer (score 4):

Segundo essa resposta no ***[SO-EN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17630945/is-there-an-opposite-to-displaynone)*** `display: none` não tem um oposto como `visibility:hidden`(oposto `visibility: visible`).

A propriedade display, no entanto, decide quais as regras de Layout que um elemento seguirá. Existem vários tipos diferentes de regras de como elementos irá ser exibidos no `CSS`, por isso existem vários valores diferentes(block, inline, inline-block, etc - [**Documentação**](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#display-prop)).

`Display:none` Remove um elemento do layout da página inteiramente, como se ele não estivesse lá.

Todos os outros valores para display causa no elemento a ser uma parte da página, neste sentido todos são opostos para `display:none,`mas não há um valor que é o inverso direto de `display:none.`

Answer (score 3):

Depende de qual o valor inicial. [Segundo a MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display) o valor inicial, se nada tiver sido aplicado ao elemento é `inline`. Porém isso não se aplica para todos os elementos. Há um [artigo interessante](https://www.impressivewebs.com/default-css-display-values-html-elements/) sobre elementos que criam um bloco no layout e outros que são *inline*, se inserem na linha em questão sem quebrar o layout ou criar um espaço próprio.

`<div>, <article>, <p>, <h...>` são alguns dos elementos que geram o seu próprio bloco de layout. Podes ver a [lista completa aqui](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Block-level_elements). Esses elementos têm o valor inicial de `block`.

`<a>, <span>, <img>` são alguns dos elementos que **não** geram o seu próprio bloco de layout. Podes ver a [lista completa aqui](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Inline_elements). Esses elementos têm o valor inicial de `inline`.

Podes também ler o valor (caso ele tenha sido defenido por CSS ou direto no style do elemento), assim podes guardar esse valor e repor depois:

```
var inicial = window.getComputedStyle(el).style;
```